# Avoiding dependency hell in file exporter for node based file type?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm struggling to come up with a proper design pattern for a VRML file exporter I'm writing. Your typical VRML file has a hierarchy like so:

```
Transform {
translation 0 0 100
    children [
        Shape { 
            appearance Appearance { 
                texture ImageTexture { 
                    repeatS TRUE 
                    repeatT TRUE 
                    url [ 
                        "texture.png" 
                    ] 
                } # end texture 

            } # end appearance 

            geometry IndexedFaceSet { 
                normalPerVertex TRUE 
                solid TRUE 
                coord Coordinate { 
                    point [ 
                        -5.400000 0.030000 -0.000000,
                        ...
                    ]  # end point 
                } # end coord 

                texCoord TextureCoordinate { 
                    point [ 
                        0.062500 0.086207,
                        ...
                    ]  # end point 
                } # end texCoord 


        normal Normal {
            vector [
                0 1 0,
            ]
        } # end normals
                coordIndex [ 
                    0, 1, 2, -1,
                    ...
                ] # end coordIndex 

                texCoordIndex [ 
                    0, 1, 2, -1,
                    ...
                ] # end texCoordIndex 
                normalIndex [ 
                    0, 0, 0, -1,
                    ...
                ] # end normalIndex 
            } # end geometry 
        } # end shape 
    ] # end children
} # end Transform
```

Right now I'm inheriting from a base class called Node that has your basic start/end strings. This is starting to create dependency hell though. Here's an example:

```
#include "IndexedFaceSetNode.h"
#include "TextureCoodinateNode.h"
#include "NormalNode.h"

struct GeometryNode : Node 
{
    IndexedFaceSetNode* indexedFaceSet;
    TextureCoordinateNode textureCoordinate;
    NormalNode normal;

    GeometryNode(string isNormalNodePerVertex, string isSolid, vector<float> coordinates, vector<int> ind) :
    Node("\tGeometryNode IndexedFaceSet { \n",
        "\t}\n")
    {
        indexedFaceSet = new IndexedFaceSetNode(isNormalNodePerVertex, isSolid, coordinates, ind);
    }

};
```

What can I do about this? Is there a better pattern or OOP structure I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a closer look at the **composite pattern**.

It is useful for building tree structures and allows treating branch and leaf components the same way by using a common abstraction.

You could use a common abstraction like Node (aka Component in the context of the pattern) in order to treat all child elements in your GeometryNode class uniformly.

As a consequence, you have to use polymorphism by overriding methods and maybe runtime checks plus casts in order to perform specific behavior.

There are several variations having different advantages and disadvantages.
So I recommend studying the pattern in detail before you decide how to improve your implementation.

E.g. for a basic understanding [Composite pattern Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)
or more detailed: [Composite pattern presentation](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~tarr/dp/lectures/Composite.pdf)

Comment: Found this which was very useful as well. Thanks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance